# eloquent - get sum of relationship column

Tags: laravel, eloquent

My models are structured this way:

```
Stock (hasMany) StockItem
StockItem (belongsTo) Shipment
Shipment (hasMany) StockItem
 - item_cost = double
```

So I'm trying to get all items and sum of their total_cost (located at Shipment model).

```
    public function getStockItemsTotalCost($stockItemId=null){
      $q = $this->stockItems()->where('id','=',$stockItemId)->with('shipment')->withCount([
        'shipment AS cost_total' => function ($query) {
          $query->select(DB::raw("SUM(item_cost) AS cost_total"));
        }
      ]);
      print_r($q);exit;
    }
```

This is returning `Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted` error.

Is this the best way to do this query?

---

I got a small progress

```
    public function getStockItemSumCost($stockItemId){
      $q = $this->stockItems()->whereHas('stockPart', function($q) use ($stockItemId) {
        return $q->where('id', '=', $stockItemId);
      })->with('shipment')
      ->get();

      print_r($q->toArray());exit;
    }
```

This is returning a StockItem list with Shipment inside each one...
What I need is a single column with the SUM() of all Shipment.item_cost column.

Comment: You need to execute the query: `])->get();`

Comment: oh thanks. now it is returning zero items

Comment: I am little bit confused! why you using them, since there is easier way! like relation!

Comment: How are you calling `getStockItemsTotalCost()`?

Comment: Is there the relation is, every stoke has one shipment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved with:

```
    public function getStockItemSumCost($stockItemId){
      $q = $this->stockItems()
      ->whereHas('stockPart', function($q) use ($stockItemId) { return $q->where('id', '=', $stockItemId); })
      ->join('shipments', 'stock_items.shipment_id', '=', 'shipments.id')
      ->sum('item_cost');

      return $q;
    }
```

Comment: It's nice if you upvote the comment that has helped you out and/or mark your question as resolved.